# Outlook 2007 add-in - What event occurs when an user moves an email from a folder to another one?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I am writing an Outlook 2007 add-in. I would like to know what event occurs when user moves an email from a folder to another one (with drag and drop or with move to folder option). My application represents a spam filter, I have a Spam folder, and I need to know whenever user moves an email form inbox to spam or form spam to inbox (this means for me that the email was wrong classified and I have to retrain it).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about [Folder.BeforeItemMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147840.aspx)?

Comment: Or [Folder.Items.ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220152(v=office.12).aspx). if it moves to your folder. (But it is not reliable)

Answer (score 2):

Install the tool [Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) then try out your experiment and see what events Outlook fires under the hood

Answer (score 0):

[Spambayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) is a popular Open Source spam filter, which works exactly the way you describe - have a look at how it does it.

Comment: Bayesian classifier is actually what  I implemented in my application